# How can I make QueryDSL code?

Tags: querydsl

I want to move this query using Query DSL. How can I do this?

Constraints

1. TB_FR_MENU_AUTH_MAP and TB_FR_MENU_PAGE_INFO is not related directly but they are connected through one other table.
2. it has dynamic query.

   ```
   SELECT B.PAGE_URL, A.WORKGROUP_SQ 
   FROM TB_FR_MENU_AUTH_MAP A INNER JOIN TB_FR_MENU_PAGE_INFO B
       ON A.MENU_SQ = B.MENU_SQ 
       AND ((B.READ_YN = 1 AND B.UPDATE_YN = 0 AND B.EXECUTE_YN = 0 AND A.READ_YN = B.READ_YN) OR
           (B.READ_YN = 0 AND B.UPDATE_YN = 1 AND B.EXECUTE_YN = 0 AND A.UPDATE_YN = B.UPDATE_YN) OR
           (B.READ_YN = 0 AND B.UPDATE_YN = 0 AND B.EXECUTE_YN = 1 AND A.EXECUTE_YN = B.EXECUTE_YN))
   WHERE 1=1
   <if test="pageUrl != null ">
       AND B.PAGE_URL = #{pageUrl}
   </if>
   ```